Reshape an image with ImageMagick
I know I can resize a image with ImageMagick using -resize or -scale, but how can I reshape a image with ImageMagick? If I use -resize or -scale:
magick image.png -resize 160x a.png
magick image.png -scale 160x b.png

I will get this:

But I want to have exactly the same number of pixels with exactly the same values in exactly the same order, but they will be "re-flowed" if that is a word into a different shape.
I have already worked out how to do it with Python Imaging Library and Numpy. My starting image is 80x80 and looks like this:

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('a.png').convert('RGB')

npArray = np.array(image)

Image.fromarray(npArray.reshape(-1,160,3)).save('largeur160.png')
Image.fromarray(npArray.reshape(-1,40,3)).save('largeur40.png')
Image.fromarray(npArray.reshape(-1,10,3)).save('largeur10.png')

I get these images with width 160, and 40 and 10:




Would it not be better to use svg?

Sorry, I don't understand how svg can edit my PNG image.

svg are just text files, take a look at one.

Cool question! Basically, I think you need to arrange all the pixels in your image into one long row, then chop up the row into chunks of the width you want. I'll do it in steps - jump to the end if you just want the answer!
First, slice your image into rows 1px tall, that gives you 80 rows of pixels, each row being 80x1:
magick input.png +repage -crop x1 info:
input.png[0] PNG 80x1 80x80+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.002
input.png[1] PNG 80x1 80x80+0+1 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.002
input.png[2] PNG 80x1 80x80+0+2 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.002
...
...
input.png[78] PNG 80x1 80x80+0+78 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.002
input.png[79] PNG 80x1 80x80+0+79 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.002

Now, concatenate all those rows together left-to-right to give all your pixels in one long row 6400x1:
magick input.png +repage -crop x1 +append info:
input.png PNG 6400x1 80x80+0+0 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.000

Now chop up that long row into lines of the new width you want, so you'll get 40 rows of 160x1:
magick input.png +repage -crop x1 +append +repage -crop 160x info:
input.png[0] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.001
input.png[1] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.001
input.png[2] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.001
input.png[3] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.001
...
...
input.png[38] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.000
input.png[39] PNG 160x1 8-bit sRGB 414B 0.000u 0:00.000

Now concatenate those rows together top-to-bottom to get your result:
magick input.png +repage -crop x1 +append +repage -crop 160x +repage -append result.png


Change the 160x to 40x and 10x for your other widths.
